# How to find $f(x)$ for $x^{m-n}-x^{m-2n+3}+x^{m-2n+1}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $f(x)$ such that:

$$(x^{m-n+1}+x^{m-n}-1)f(x)+x^{m-2n+1}(x^{n}+x^2-1)=x^{m-n}-x^{m-2n+3}+x^{m-2n+1}-1$$

This is for my number theory problem: Find all $(m;n)$ with $m,n \geq 3$ such that $$\frac{x^m+x-1}{x^n+x^2-1} \in \mathbb{N}^* , \forall x\in \mathbb{N}^*$$

So my teacher said I need to find the $f(x)$ for the problem! I have tried by finding it by hand, and it seem very difficult, I tried this: $f(x)=-x^{2-n} + x^{1-n}-1$ but it still not correct!
Anyone have the better method? Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: It means all positive integer numbers exept $0$

Comment: I am confused about what you are asking here. What does $f(x)$ have to do with your number theory problem "Find all $(m,n),\ldots?$"

Comment: I don't know, my teacher if I can find $f(x)$ he will show us the solution

Comment: Did your teacher say that $f(x)$ is a polynomial? For $f(x)$ to be a polynomial, very strong conditions will be imposed on $m$ and $n$.

Comment: What is hard about finding $f$? Simplify the polynomial expressions and move all terms without $f$ to the other side, then divide by the multiplier of $f$. Voila!

Comment: I can't understand, I want to make $f(x)= ax^p + bx^q + cx^r + d$ but it seem very complicated